# How to work with Spring Cloud during development phase?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I study actually Spring Cloud and the way to work with it is not very clear for me, especially during the development phase.

During development phase, does the developer can or must use a local configuration ?

What about getting the configuration when the Spring Cloud Server configured in bootstrap.yml is down ?

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with static file configuration for development.If the path specified in bootstrap.yml is down then you will get PropertyPlaceHolder exceptions.

For production you can configure all your configuration files in github and you can configure the git uri in bootstrap.yml.

Please read [this](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Brixton.SR7/) for more clarifications, It's pretty clear also you can find all the questions related to spring-cloud [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-cloud).

Comment: You can use spring profiles also, like 'development'.